# Query to find all equal values from 2 list of string columns

Tags: java, sql, spring-data-jpa

I have this data:

```
tconst   directors                    writers
0001     gorge miller, johny amido    sarah blake
0002,    tom kaver                    tom kaver
0003,    bob marley                   bob marley, nicole jamine
```

I want to write a query to find all items (between directors and writers columns) that its directors and writers are the same or at the least exist one common item, for example, I want to write a query to give me  items: 0002 and 0003 from my table:

```
0002,    tom kaver                    tom kaver
0003,    bob marley                   bob marley, nicole jamine
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I would suggest you properly normalise your data, storing delimited data is a common anti-pattern making your solution harder and poor performing than it need be.

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using? Don't make us guess, it just makes it harder to help you.

Comment: @AaronBertrand i do not use SQL server, actually i am Java developer using Java and Spring data framework, i wanted to find a logical SQL query at the first step then i should convert it for Java, so you can consider i am using SQL 2016 and later versions

Comment: I don't understand - you don't use SQL Server? Why is it tagged SQL Server?

Comment: @AaronBertrand you are right, i fixed the tags

Answer (score 2):

You want to split both sides and match; assuming SQL Server 2016 or above:

```
SELECT tconst, directors, writers
FROM dbo.whoknows AS wk
WHERE EXISTS
(
  SELECT 1 FROM dbo.whoknows AS t
  CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(directors,',') AS d
  CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(writers,  ',') AS w
  WHERE LTRIM(RTRIM(d.value)) = LTRIM(RTRIM(w.value))
  AND t.tconst = wk.tconst
);
```

(Or properly normalize your tables, as Stu suggested. You shouldn't combine two names in a single column unless you never, ever, ever need to query against individual names like this.)

| tconst | directors | writers |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0002 | tom kaver | tom kaver |
| 0003 | bob marley | bob marley, nicole jamine |

- [Working db<>fiddle example](https://dbfiddle.uk/TIBYmby8?hide=4).